Range of R^2 in a 2 feature centered OLS
Note: this question has appeared many times here, but there are conflicting answers; therefore I wanted to post it here again to ask for clarifications.
Problem at hand:
Do OLS regression on y ~x1, y~x2, get two R^2 r1, r2 respectively (assuming everything centered). Now do full regression y ~ x1 + x2. What is the TIGHTEST range of R^2?
ALSO, WHAT IS THE SITUATION WHEN R^2 = r1 + r2?
Conflicting answers:
Answer one: range = [max(r1, r2), 1]
(as supported in this post: Range of values of $R^2$ for a two-feature linear model based on the $R^2$s of one-feature linear models?
Answer two: range = [max(r1, r2), min(r1+r2, 1)]
(as supported in this post: Range of $R^2$ of the model with two predictors given the $R^2$s of univariate models of each predictor)
Which one should be correct?
Here is my thoughts: I'm leaning towards answer 1 because, geometrically speaking, if x1, x2, and y are coplanar, which is always possible no matter what r1 and r2 is as long as dimension > 3 (since all the centered vectors in R3 form a 2-D plane) then the tightest upperbound should simply always be 1, no?
I'm also confused about when will the R2 in the full model exactly equal to r1 + r2, assuming r1 != r2?
Also when will R2 = max(r1, r2)? One solution in the links I proposed above proposed that this happens when x1(assuming the less correlated one) is orthogonal to the plane generated by y and x2. But my doubt is: if so, x1 will be forced to be perpendicular to y as well, which will force r1 to be 0, but that's too restrictive and r1 is supposed to be anything number.

See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155968/relation-between-r2-of-simple-regression-and-multiple-regression/156024#156024

So essentially answer one should be right, correct?

That is my view, yes
